# Android ImageView with ListView, where ImageView scrolls slightly up when user tries to scroll down

Tags: android, image, listview, view, scroll

I have to create a layout which looks like this. It has an image view with a listview below that.

What I want is, when the user tries to scroll down, first the image view will move up to leave a very small portion of the image view visible, so as to make the space allocated to listview more. Only after the image has scrolled up to its new position, then the listview starts scrolling, not before that.

Again, while scrolling up, once the user has reached the top of listview, then the image view should again scroll down to be visible fully.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check :https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView
else :https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView

```
mListView = (ParallaxScollListView) findViewById(R.id.layout_listview);
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
mImageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.layout_header_image);

mListView.setParallaxImageView(mImageView);
mListView.addHeaderView(header);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
        new String[]{
                "First Item",
                "Second Item",
                "Third Item",
                "Fifth Item",
                "Sixth Item",
                "Seventh Item",
                "Eighth Item",
                "Ninth Item",
                "Tenth Item",
                "....."
        }
);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
Make a custom ListView.
And another layout (layout_header.xml)containing single Image view(headImage).Set this layout as your list view's first object.

And make a customListView.java. Your customlistView.java will look like this. I have skipped basic portions hope you can fill it.

```
public class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public CustomList(Activity context,  etc params) { 
  **Your Code
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,View view, ViewGroup parent){
    View rowView;
 if (position == 0){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header, parent, false);

        ImageView bannerImage = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.headImage);
```

the problem is that the image at the top will be scrolled up completely with list